# Swift 2.1 Core Data - Saving relationship creates an empty record

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My project has Category and Recipe entity which has one to many relationship.

When a user creates a new recipe, selecting category is optional.
If not selected, a default category will be used to establish relationship with a recipe.

When `createRecipe()` is fired, it will add correct category relationship to Recipe entity. But the problem is, there will be an empty record added in Category entity.

I made sure both `changedCategory` and `defaultCategory` are not `""` so not sure why I'm seeing this `""` added in Category entity.
I'm checking the data entry with sqlitebrowser.

How do I prevent en empty record being added to Category entity with the following code?

```
func createRecipe(sender: AnyObject!) {

    if let title = recipeTitle.text where title != "" {
        let category = obtainCategoryEntity(changedCategory, defaultCategory: defaultCategory, context: self.context)
        let recipe = (NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Recipe", inManagedObjectContext: self.context) as! Recipe)

        recipe.category = category

        recipe.title = title
        ...

        do {
            try self.context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Could not save recipe")
        }    
    }
}

func obtainCategoryEntity(changedCategory: String, defaultCategory: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> RecipeCategory {

    var category = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("RecipeCategory", inManagedObjectContext: self.context) as! RecipeCategory

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "RecipeCategory")

    if changedCategory != "" {
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", changedCategory)
    } else {
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", defaultCategory)
    }

    if let results = (try? context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)) as? [RecipeCategory] {
        if results.count > 0 {
            category = results[0]
        }
    }

    return category
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In obtainCategoryEntity, you need to set category.name to either changedCategory or defaultCategory if the fetch request does not find an existing category with that name.

Comment: Thanks. I have category.name = categoryEntity in Create(). Wouldn't it be a duplicate?

Comment: And there won't be a case where fetch request doesn't find existing category. I'm doing this checking in the Category viewcontroller which I haven't shown here.

Comment: I notice you've answered my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36346733/swift-2-1-core-data-save-data-that-has-one-to-many-relationship-but-dont-add. Since that question, things changed a little bit and I've applied your code to Category viewcontroller where adding a new category and duplicate checking is necessary. In the CreateRecipe viewcontroller mentioned in this question, I merely obtain the category entity and assign relationship but it unexpectedly creates an empty category record.

Comment: As written, obtainCategoryEntity always inserts a new category entity. That's what NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName does. And it will always be blank because you did not set category.name after inserting it. If your intention is to retrieve an existing category, and you are certain it will always exist, then you should write a different function that does not call insertNewObjectForEntityForName.

Comment: In the original code I posted, the call to insert a category came after the fetch. You moved it before the fetch and that is why one is always getting created.